# Sorting a no-ordered sequential coordinate to get a outline of zone

Tags: algorithm, sorting, date-sorting

The input is a sequence which has gotten when I find a outline from a zone.
This sequence is consist of pixels surrounding this zone.

But this sequence isn't ordered due to use recursive when i got the sequence.
How can I sort this sequence?

The Output should be a circuit which start and end at the same point and pass through all the point(maybe a few point can ignore if necessary).

Comment: Did you forget to specify that the generated circuit should be as small as possible? Because then you're rediscovering the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: Also, you failed to show any effort into solving this

Comment: Is the zone guaranteed to be convex?

Answer (score 0):

If the zone is convex, then all you need to do is to find the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) for the set of pixels. If the zone can be concave as well then you can not possibly solve the problem - the outline can be reconstructed in many ways and each of them would be equally probable(unless further information is provided).

Comment: I'm sorry that the description isn't detail enough.
The zone can be concave as well.
May be recovering the true outline is impossible.
But can we get the nearest outline between it and original outline?

Comment: But if the zone can be concave and the  the points are randomly shuffled then you can not have even an approximation. Most permutations of the points will be valid outline of a concave zone.  As gou have no further information gou can't distinguish between them and any outline will look equally plausible

Comment: I think the only information is that every outline are pixel, so each outline' pixel will always have one or several pixel neighbor.

Answer (score 0):

You say that these points of yours represent an outline of some region. If that is indeed true you can go and simply search for nearest neighbours.

But this alone can be quite slow so make sure you implement some heuristics to lower the number of distances between points you need to calculate in order to find the nearest neighbours.

The easiest way would be to divide your world into grid like pattern and then first try searching for possible neighbours in same grid cell than your origin point is.

And if the distance to all points that are in same grid cells is larger than the distance from the point of origin to the nearest cell border also check the points in that neighbouring grid cell that share the same border.

The biggest advantage of this approach is that it doesn't care if the region shape is convex or concave.